# Comparing list to determine correct position within List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two lists that I need to compare:

```
var list = new Guess(guesses, 0 , 0);// see class for constructor
```

and

```
theGame.Target = guesses;
var list2 = theGame.Target;
```

I need to do the following:

`GuessTheDigits` Sets The Number Of `RightDigitsInTheRightPosition` Correctly

**GuessTheDigits:**

```
public ActionResult GuessTheDigits(List<int> guesses)
{
    GuessingGame theGame = this.Session["GameState"] as GuessingGame;

    // pass to the method
    theGame.GuessTheHiddenDigits(guesses);

    //set the lists
    var list = new Guess();

    theGame.Target = guesses;

    var list2 = theGame.Target;

    //need to compare lists here

    // Redirect to action
    return RedirectToAction("Index", theGame.Guesses);
}
```

**Classes as follows:**

**Guess Class**

```
public class Guess
{
    public Guess()
        : this(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 }, 0, 0 )
    {

    }
    public Guess(List<int> guesses, int rdrp, int rdwp)
    {
        this.Digits = guesses;
        this.RightDigitRightPosition = rdrp;
        this.RightDigitWrongPosition = rdwp;
    }

    public Guess(List<int> guesses, int rdrp)
        : this(guesses, rdrp, 0)
    {

    }

    public Guess(List<int> guesses)
       : this(guesses, 0, 0)
    {

    }

    public List<int> Digits { get; set; }
    public int RightDigitRightPosition { get; set; }
    public int RightDigitWrongPosition { get; set; }
}
```

**Previously tried code:**

```
var check = list2.Where(s => !theGame.Guesses.Contains(list));
foreach (var i in check)
{
    list.RightDigitRightPosition = i;
}
```

Comment: _"Previously tried code"_ did it work? If not, what was going wrong?

Comment: I'll be honest, it's still not all that clear what you're trying to do. Please try to explain the goal in a very concise manner.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - it isn't comparing the lists and is instead assigning `list.RightDigitRightPosition` to the value of each item in the list

Comment: What's the type for `theGame.Guesses`, is it `List<Guess>`? The `list` variable is not actually a list but a `Guess`. I think you might be mixing things up in your code.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

Presuming `theGame.Guesses` is `List<Guess>` then I *think* (because it's not entirely clear) the code you are after is

```
var samePositions = myGame.Guesses.Where(x => list.Digits.IndexOf(x.RightDigitRightPosition) == x.Digits.IndexOf(x.RightDigitRightPosition)));
```

This is pulling all the guesses that have the `RightDigitRightPosition` value and in the same position as `list` has.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IndexOf` to find the position of a value:

```
int i = this.Digits.IndexOf(value);
```

It's unclear *how* `RightDigitRightPosition` and `RightDigitWrongPosition` are supposed to be set to know exactly how to do that.